# Google map is not working on mvc web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, google-maps

I have created mvc3 web app and i want to gmap on my contact page

```
ERROR:
Google has disabled use of the Maps API for this application. The provided key is not a valid Google API Key, or it is not authorized for the Google Maps Javascript API v2 on this site. If you are the owner of this application, you can learn about obtaining a valid key here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#Obtaining_Key
```

code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAASszoPf7kpR6gGrbmCayD7oU1BTox11w&sensor=false">
</script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var allMarks = [];
        google.load("maps", "2");

        //This function will help us to add the mark at
        //location where user has double clicked. Then
        //we will add all the marks in our array so that
        //we can send it back to the controller
        function initialize() {
            var map = new google.maps.Map2(document.getElementById("map"));
            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419), 13);
            map.setUIToDefault();
            GEvent.addListener(map, "dblclick", function(overlay, latlng) {
                if (latlng) {
                    var mark = new GMarker(latlng);
                    allMarks.push(latlng);
                    map.addOverlay(mark);
                }
            });

        }
</script>
```

buti dont see the map also i failed to generate the api key from :

```
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html
```

I want to test it on my local machine plz help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you using an API key?

It is no longer required unless you need usage reports, or you want to purchase [additional quota](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/usage.html) if your website generates more than 25 000 map loads per day.

To use the [Google Libraries API](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html), you just have to include the following script in the header of your web page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Also, the Google Maps Javascript API Version 2 has been officially deprecated, so you should use the new [version 3](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html) of the Maps Javascript API.

```
var allMarks = [];
google.load('maps','3', {other_params: "sensor=false"});

function initialize() {
    var options = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "dblclick", function(e) {
        if (e.latLng) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: e.latLng,
                map: map
            });
            allMarks.push(e.latLng);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register an API for local testing by using http://localhost/